# Does anybody know why the new edition of Thomas' Calculus leaves out an important property of surface integrals?

Tags: soft-question

[image]

Does anybody here think it's intentional? It seems like such a useful thing to know, why would anybody want to  scrap that?

Comment: Yeah, I dont know, but I have noticed that students have become much more unfamillar with notation like $df=f^{\prime}dx$. I always have to explain the simpler notation for integration by parts. I suspect there is a general push on the part of lecturers against this notation, and this omission seems to be along those lines. (Ha, a pun !)

Comment: Interesting, I wonder why. I mean, in this case it's clearly an important bit of notation being omitted here by the authors on the subject of surface integral notation, right?

Comment: I wouldn't say "property" in the question title when what is really involved is a notation. Frankly, unless the notation was used again in the chapter, defining it there seems pointless. Do students actually retain definitions that they don't use--even ones that they use a little but not a lot? Don't you end up having to teach the material again when you need it anyway?

Comment: @DavidK Sure, but in the next section on Stokes' theorem, he ends up using the notation he left out in the new edition. Without explaining it... Doesn't seem very pedagogical.

Comment: Well, _that_ seems like a mistake.